# how to make a layout on half screen

Tags: android, layout, material-design

hi I'm new to android and I'm interested in learning how it is done or what name has the functionality of the screenshot that I uploaded

Thanks for the help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqq5I.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the bottom sheet. You can check out example [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)